# Volume estimation using Intel RealSense D435 Camera

Tags: python-3.6, realsense, open3d

I'm currently working on a project that requires volume estimation in (almost) real time. I have one Intel RealSense D435 depth camera. Objects (mainly piles of boxes) are seen from above. I want to estimate the volume of those objects using the pyrealsense2 pointcloud feature, but I'm unable to find any way to do so.

I've looked at the code samples on the intel realsense GitHub page, but they weren't helpful at all.
I've tried to use PCL and its Python wrapper but the wrapper isn't stable on Ubuntu 18.04.
I've also tried to use Open3D and estimate the volume of the bouding box of the pointcloud, but the results aren't accurate at all (moving from 14 to 253 whithin two frames).

I'm quite new in this aera and don't really know where to look or what to try to improve things. Any suggestions ?